# C++ event processing

Tags: c++, events, boost, boost-asio

I am using the excellent `asio` for an asynchronous network client. When handling read  (`async_read`) I am concerned that the method/function handling the data might hang or take too long (the function is supplied by the user of the class).

What is the best way of calling the supplied function *and* ensuring it won't take too long ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper function which launches the given handler in a separate thread and does a timed_join on it. If the timeout reaches, you could throw an exception or do whatever else you want.

Comment: This is very interesting. How do I launch a function/method in another thread ?

Comment: @nc3b: you create an instance of boost::thread class (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) and pass the function/method as the argument. The abovementioned timed_join is the member of boost::thread class.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I could do this, but spawning another thread for each packet received might be a bit of a performance hit

Comment: @nc3b: Good point, on the other hand, you could optimize this idea, for example using a thread pool, in which case you wouldn't have to spawn new threads all the time

Comment: Using `Boost.Thread` can I put a thread to sleep and signal it when more data is available ?

Comment: @n3cb: Yes, for example with a condition_variable. Basically if you read the documentation of boost::thread, you will get all the answers, including how to spawn/manipulate threads and how to do synchronization.

Comment: "The classes condition_variable  and condition_variable_any  provide a mechanism for one thread to wait for notification from another thread that a particular condition has become true." This seems to be exactly what I need, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples provided by the boost documentation that describe what you are wanting to accomplish.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

look under the section titled timeouts for the examples.

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? I am quite new to boost and a little guidance would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the work your handler does is very short-lived (unlikely in a real world application), you are going to want a producer/consumer queue to hand off the received data from your I/O thread(s) to your worker thraed(s) for further processing, so you can return from your handler asap.

There is a primer on producer/consumer using Boost.Thread [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) - written by the current author of the Boost Threads library, as a bonus.

Comment: @nc3b - I cannot say enough good things about these parts of Boost.

Answer (score 1):

An extra thread(s) to handle the callback processing is a good idea.  As mentioned above, having your callback push a message onto a thread safe queue and another thread consuming/processing the message works great.

Another threading scenario that may work for you is to just start additional threads on the io_service.  These additional threads will make it possible to process several handlers at the same time.

```
const int max_threads = 5;
boost::asio::io_service ios;
boost::thread_group thread_group;

for (int i = 0 ; i < max_threads; ++i)
  thread_group.create_thread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, boost::ref(ios)) );
```

The correct solution really depends on what the application is doing.  If this is a TCP connection and the messages need to be processed in sequential order consider using the producer/consumer queue.  If the messages are independent of each other and do not require that they are processed in order then this approach is suitable as well.

If its a UDP connection then all bets are off anyway because the ordering of the received messages is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I ended up with a producer/consumer model (as the messages are processed in sequential order).